# Split sample in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a variable X containing 3100 values. 
I need to split X into variable Y and Z. Y containing 1500 first values of X and Z containing the rest of X.
I'm not sure whether it works with

```
split X
```

or any other code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it?

`split` is for splitting strings and for splitting them into parts according to their contents.

You appear to want something like `separate X, by(_n <= 1500)` followed by renaming if you wish. Two `generate` statements would also work fine.